# create a responsive svg with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg

I want to create an svg that will be easily scaled on whatever width I'll give it. In that svg I have a circle and path with relative paths so I want it to be easily scaleable.

But for some reason the position of x,y are not right.

You can see the image below, the circle has (x,y)=(0,0)
but it is set in the middle.
I assume "viewBox" is causing problems.

[image]

jsfiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/tzookb/69z2wepo/174297/

code:

```
const ExclamationIcon = props => (
    <svg {...props} viewBox="0 0 140 140">
      <circle fill="#f66868" cx="70" cy="70" r="70" />
      <g transform="translate(58,30)">
        <path fill="white" d="M 11,56.7 L 9,56.7 L 4.2,13.2 C 4,11.4 4,10 4,9 C 4,7 4.5,4.9 5.6,3.5 C 7,2.2 8.3,1.5 10,1.5 C 11.7,1.5 13,2.2 14.4,3.5 C 15.5,4.9 16,7 16,9 C 16,10 16,11.4 15.8,13.2 z M 10,64 A 6,6 0 1,1 10,76 A 6,6 0 1,1 10,64 z"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
);


class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        asdas
        <svg className="main">
          <rect x="20" y="20" width="100" height="40" fill="red" />

          <ExclamationIcon width="30" x="0" y="0" />
        </svg>


      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: That is very curious behaviour. Any particular reason we are using the outer SVG? Which SVG do you want to make responsive? The outer svg or the svg as created by `ExclamationIcon`?

Comment: The second svg should be responsive. I use it as simple icon in html but I had to use it in an svg and got this error :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this issue goes away if the height is set on the inner svg. I'm guessing that if the height is not set it automatically takes up all the available height and centres itself. I wish I had a better explanation but this completely stumped me.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/174448/)

```js
const ExclamationIcon = props => (
    <svg {...props} viewBox="0 0 140 140">
      <circle fill="#f66868" cx="70" cy="70" r="70" />
      <g transform="translate(58,30)">
        <path fill="white" d="M 11,56.7 L 9,56.7 L 4.2,13.2 C 4,11.4 4,10 4,9 C 4,7 4.5,4.9 5.6,3.5 C 7,2.2 8.3,1.5 10,1.5 C 11.7,1.5 13,2.2 14.4,3.5 C 15.5,4.9 16,7 16,9 C 16,10 16,11.4 15.8,13.2 z M 10,64 A 6,6 0 1,1 10,76 A 6,6 0 1,1 10,64 z"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
);


class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
        asdas
        <svg className="main">
          <rect x="20" y="20" width="100" height="40" fill="red" />

          <ExclamationIcon width="30" height="30" x="0" y="0" />
        </svg>

      
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```